# putting socket connection to dormant state while waiting for data from server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, interrupt

I have a client socket connected to the server socket, the server will send data to the client from time to time while its connected. currently my client uses a while loop to keep receiving data from the server even the server is not sending anything.

my question is, is there any more efficient way to listen for input?

i am thinking maybe create a thread for the socket connection, and put it to sleep when there is no incoming data, and sends an interrupt when there is data coming in. would that work? if putting the thread to sleep, would it break the socket connection?

i cannot modify the server socket and it doesnt initiate a connection.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class core_socket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = ("192.168.100.206");
        int port = 4025;
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

            System.out.println("created socket\n");
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            boolean autoflush = true;
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), autoflush);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            // read the response
            boolean loop = true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8096);
            while (loop) {
                if (in.ready()) {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i != -1) {
                        i = in.read();
                        sb.append((char) i);
                    }
                    loop = false;
                }
            }

            // display the response to the out console
            System.out.println(sb.toString());

            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See multi-user chat application example at http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/ - basically, you should consider spawning off a new worker thread for each incoming connection and then go back to listen for any new incoming requests.

A long time ago I wrote one of the first application servers (say in 1997 when most people didn't know what an app server is) - it was deployed at one of the largest higher-ed institutions and processed couple million requests per day during peak times - that's not the institution in the link by the way. The reason I mention this is... multi-threading gives you a tremendous scalability with very little effort - even if scalability is not what you are looking for, worker thread model is still a good practice.

Comment: multi-threading gives you no scalability, since the context switches takes a lot of time. Actually, the multi-threading model is the worst, take a look at this : [Kegel's C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html)

Comment: @nouney thank you for sharing this link. I wish I had enough time on hand to read through and comprehend all of it. For now, I trued to help using what I know - if that's not the right solution, I am sure someone else will have it. Also, I didn't think the original questioner needed any level of high scalability because a sophisticated implementation is far more difficult then what can be addressed in a forum like this one.

Comment: @nouney and smallworld, thank you for the links, they are wonderful, I will read more into them and post back questions if I encounter any.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is to use asynchronous sockets. Basically, it spins off another thread that's job is to listen for any data on the socket. Once data does come in, a "callback" method is called, which can then begin to process your data.

I've never done sockets in Java before though, just C#, so I'm not sure how it compares, but the concept should remain the same.